# fncychap package - vertical gap/space between text and heading too large - how to reduce?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, table-of-contents, chapters, fncychap

The below example shows the table large gap between the top of the table of contents its section heading.
How can this gap be reduced?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents 
\chapter{This is an unnecessary huge gap!!?}
Here is some text in the section.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! It's better to format the whole example (including the preamble) as a code sample -- I did this for you. I also removed the {parskip} tag which is about the package of the same name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the change in vertical spacing should affect only the title "Contents" and the first entry in the Table of Contents, an `\addtocontents` command should be enough:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip-40pt}
\chapter{Test chapter}
Here is some text in the section.

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Gonzalo and \addtocontents{toc}{\vskip-120pt}.  This worked very well and as expected.

Comment: @Gonzalo, if using the hyperref package (\usepackage(hyperref})
 in the preamble, "\vskip-60ptTable of Contents" is inserted into the link and not simply "Table of Contents".  Any idea how to fix?

Comment: @Gonzalo, further to this.  The word "Table of Contents" in the table of contents is shifted to the right an extra 11 characters due to size of the phrase "\vskip-60pt".  How can the text be shifted left and hence left aligned?

Comment: @Ian: I don't see any of those undesired effects after adding `\usepackage{hyperref}` right before `\begin{document}` in my example code. If you are experiencing some undesired behaviour, it would be appropriate to open a new question exposing your problem in detail (and including a MWE).

Comment: @Gonzalo, As suggested:  I followed the vertical alignment undesired result in the post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13351/fncychap-package-vertical-gap-space-between-text-and-heading-too-large-shift

Comment: @Ian: I already provided an answer to the new question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That really helped me. However, I need to do the same for toF and toT, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Add the following immediately before `\begin{document}` (halves vertical space):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\DOTI}{\vskip 40\p@}{\vskip 20\p@}{}{}
\patchcmd{\DOTIS}{\vskip 40\p@}{\vskip 20\p@}{}{}% for unnumbered chapters
\makeatother
```

Comment: This looks somewhat like the way to do it according to the fncychap package manual.  However, I could not get your code to work as there is no change to any spacing.