# fncychap: vertical space between text and heading too large - shift left heading - improving on fix?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, table-of-contents, fncychap

To reduce space between the table of contents heading and the first entry in the table of contents the following solution is used:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip-40pt The heading to display}
```

However, this produces the undesired effect that in the table of contents the words "The heading to display" is shifted to the right by 11 characters which is the size of the text "\vskip-40pt".
How can this text be vertically left aligned with the other headings?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}

\begin{document}    
        \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\vskip-60pt The heading to display} 
        \tableofcontents                
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}        % Add another entry to the contents page    

    \chapter{Test chapter}
    Here is some text in the chapter.
    \section{A section}
    text in a section.    
\end{document}
```

This post follows the suggested solution in:
[fncychap package - vertical gap/space between text and heading too large - how to reduce?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13319/fncychap-package-vertical-gap-space-between-text-and-heading-too-large-how-to)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you see my answer in the question you linked, I used `\addtocontents` and **not** `\addcontentsline` to reduce the space between the title and the first entry; simply replace `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\vskip-60pt The heading to display}` with `\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip-60pt}` to get the desired result.

The `\addtocontents` command is mainly intended to enter **formatting information** not directly related to any contents line; it can be used, for example, to add (or subtract) additional white space in some places.

The `\addcontentsline` command, on the other hand, is intended to enter **specific information** (a new entry including some text, the page number of the current page, etc.) in the ToC.