# Gap between header and content too large with fncychap

Tags: formatting, fncychap

I am using the `fncychap` package for my book. The gap between the title and the content of a chapter is too large. I want to reduce it, so I read those two solutions :

- [fncychap package - vertical gap/space between text and heading too large - how to reduce?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13319/fncychap-package-vertical-gap-space-between-text-and-heading-too-large-how-t)
- [fncychap: vertical space between text and heading too large - shift left heading - improving on fix?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13351/fncychap-vertical-space-between-text-and-heading-too-large-shift-left-heading)

The solutions suggested in those topics didn't worked (no errors were being raised but I didn't affect the document)

**How can I reduce the space between the title and the content with `fncychap` ?**

EDIT : Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass[10pt,b5paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
% Layout :
\usepackage[twoside,bindingoffset=6mm,verbose,marginratio={4:6,5:7},
textwidth=117.3mm,height=179.6mm]{geometry} 
% ===========================================
% Polices :
\usepackage{lmodern}
% ###########################################
% HEADER
% ###########################################
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\ChNameVar{\bfseries\Large\sf}
\ChNumVar{\Huge}
\ChTitleVar{\bfseries\Large}
\ChRuleWidth{1pt}
\ChNameUpperCase
\ChTitleUpperCase
\usepackage{lipsum}
%============================================
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance for any advice.

Comment: I thought the whole purpose of packages like fancychap was to avoid modifying `\@makechapterhead` yourself.

Comment: I don't know, the solution I implemented here was one of those I found here on SX. But It doesn't work. I edited my post and deleted the implementation

Comment: Okay, in the manual there are commands like \DOCH, \DOTI and \DOTIS which contain \vskip 40pt.  These are the source of the gaps.  Modify them, not \@makechapterhead.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you, since I don't know how to properly modify these commands, I supply put after `\chapter{a chapter}` a `\vskip-60pt` to do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses etoolbox to modify the existing code from Glen.  Other styles may use different code.  For completeness, I also show how to reduce the space above the chapter.

You should remove the [showframe] option from geometry when eventually.

```
\documentclass[10pt,b5paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
% Layout :
\usepackage[twoside,bindingoffset=6mm,verbose,marginratio={4:6,5:7},
textwidth=117.3mm,height=179.6mm, showframe]{geometry} 
% ===========================================
% Polices :
\usepackage{lmodern}
% ###########################################
% HEADER
% ###########################################
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\ChNameVar{\bfseries\Large\sf}
\ChNumVar{\Huge}
\ChTitleVar{\bfseries\Large}
\ChRuleWidth{1pt}
\ChNameUpperCase
\ChTitleUpperCase

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{20\p@}}{}{FAILED 1}% change space above chapter
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{20\p@}}{}{FAILED 2}% change space above chapter*
\patchcmd{\DOTI}{\vskip 80\p@}{\vskip 20\p@}{}{FAILED 3}% change space below chapter
\patchcmd{\DOTIS}{\vskip 40\p@}{\vskip 20\p@}{}{FAILED 4}% change space below chapter*
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{lipsum}
%============================================
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```